# Importing a zero coupon curve to RQuantLib

Tags: fixed-income, rquantlib

I am trying to use a zero coupon curve constructed elsewhere to price treasury bonds in RQuantLib.

The issue is that DiscountCurve does not take zero coupon yields as inputs, but rather swap rates. I guess I could construct the swap rates from zero coupons and then pass those to DiscountCurve, but is there a more direct way?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just convert each zero coupon point into a discount factor?

Comment: no, that's what I did manually in the end. but I still can't input discount factors into a DiscountCurve object in QuantLib. Was just wondering if there was a way to do this in RQuantLib!